# Can resque and resque-scheduler jobs run in parallel?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resque, resque-scheduler

How to make resque and resque-scheduler jobs to work in parallel,
I can run 2 workers simultaneously like this

```
COUNT=2 QUEUE=* rake resque:workers
```

But when 2 resque jobs are working then resque-scheduler job is waiting in queue,
I need resque-scheduler job to run in parallel with resque job

Comment: Why not seperate them by different queues ?

Comment: @astropanic they have 2 different queues

Comment: COUNT=2 QUEUE=foo rake resque:workers ; COUNT=2 QUEUE=bar rake resque:workers - you will have for both 2 workers

Answer (score 0):

Resque allows you to use different work queues, and to set a priority list of which queues workers pull work from.

For example, if you have a queue called "batch_jobs" and a queue called "scheduled" work that's higher priority, you can run 2 workers using:

```
COUNT=2 QUEUE=scheduled,batch_jobs rake resque:workers
```

When you schedule jobs from resque-scheduler, placing them into the "scheduled" queue will cause them to be executed before jobs in the "batch_jobs" queue.

Each worker will continuously scan the QUEUES list in order, trying to find a job to work on.